# Remove specific HTML Tag in iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, html, ios, xcode, html-parsing

I have a `NSString` which contain the `HTML` content. But I want to remove `< img src=..../>` Tag form NSString.

e.g.

```
Source = < p>< a href="http://wpcore.mpf.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/thumbs_img_0500.jpg">**< img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-4730" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;" title="thumbs_img_0500" src="http://wpcore.mpf.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/thumbs_img_0500.jpg" alt="thumbs img 0500" width="120" height="120" />**< /a>The two professional level < a title="3d printing" href="http://www.makepartsfast.com/category/products/3d-printers/">3D printers< /a> that build parts in color are the Zprinter from 3D Systems and the < a href="http://www.makepartsfast.com/2012/05/3812/mcor-announces-full-3d-color-3d-printer">Iris< /a> from Mcor Technologies. Earlier this year, Mcor Technologies announced its Iris full color 3D printer at the Rapid show and recently at Euromold. The Zprinter uses ink jetted into the build powder. The Iris, however, uses a different technique for creating color parts. Dr. Conor MacCormack, CEO of Mcor, discusses this technology.</p>
< p>< a href="http://wpcore.mpf.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/MacCormack-part-1.mp3">MacCormack part 1< /a>< /p>
```

My img src tag will be different all time.
How can i do this??

My code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
source = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.parseResults objectAtIndex:k] objectForKey:@"summary"]];

NSLog(@"%@",source);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by converting HTML into string.

Just import two files **NSString+HTML.h & NSString+HTML.m** file.

Then Called **`text_str=[html_str stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText]`**;

Answer (score 0):

//do like below...let me know it is working or not!!!!

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 source = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.parseResults objectAtIndex:k] objectForKey:@"summary"]];
 Source=[self flattenHTML:Source];//call flattenhtml method...
 NSLog(@"%@",source);
}


#pragma mark ---Removing HTML Tags
- (NSString *)flattenHTML:(NSString *)html {

NSScanner *theScanner;
NSString *text = nil;
theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];

while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

    [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL] ; 

    [theScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&text] ;

}
html = [html stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

return html;
}
```

Comment: i am not telling you that you are wrong my friend, but it should work,that code always works in my every app...